# Access VBA to change unbound control .format

Tags: vba, ms-access, string.format

I have a sub form datasheet that when I double-click a row sends 10 values to unbound controls on a main form.  I would like to change the .format of the main form unbound controls based on what row I select in the sub form.  In one case, unbound control #1 needs to be a SHORT DATE.  In another, it needs to be CURRENCY. In a third it needs to be TEXT, etc...  I tried using frm.Main!UnboundControl.Format to change the format before I push values into the unbound control but that is not working.  Thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and read [ask]! `frm.Main!UnboundControl` is a typo as a form (usually declared as `frm` if stored in a var) has no `Main` method, unless you implemented one. Formating is done in the DoubleClick-Event? Then use `Me.Parent!UnboundControl.Format ` to reference the main form ftom the subform:

Comment: Not working.  Can I re-phrase?  I created an unbound control NEWDATE on my main form and created Me.NEWDATE.Format = "Short Date" in the LOAD event of the form.  When I open the form, I can still enter text into NEWDATE.  I would have expected that when I entered "3/32/2018" into NEWDATE for example, it would have given me the error message "Not a valid date".  Seems like I cannot get .Format to work programmatically.

Comment: I solved it.  Created a new unbound control in a new database and it worked.  Based on a suggestion I read elsewhere on SO, I will copy all of my current objects into a new database and try again.  Thanks for the help!